# Array always re-create itself php

Tags: php, arrays

My programm read info from textbox and show it to user, so the problems is in middle part of that operation. How to make `$myArray` don't re-create itself when i update page?

```
session_start();

if (!isset($myArray)) $myArray = array();

$myArray[] = $_POST['nameAuthor'];

foreach($myArray as $key=>$value)
{
    echo "$key->$value";    
}

//$_SESSION['arr'] = $myArray;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['arr'])) $_SESSION['arr'] =  array();

$_SESSION['arr'][] = $_POST['nameAuthor'];

foreach($_SESSION['arr'] as $key => $value)
{
    echo "$key->$value";    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it's throw: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['` in `if(!isset($_SESSION['arr'])) $_SESSION['arr'] =  [];`

Comment: Your php version is < 5.4 ;)